# How to see what SDL version I have

Tags: 14.04, versions, sdl

I am want to know what SDL version I have installed on Ubuntu.

Is there a terminal command I can run to find out?

Comment: you can use `dpkg -l *libsdl*`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dpkg -l | grep sdl` is one possible answer.

Answer (score 7):

A platform-agnostic solution may be:

```
sdl2-config --version
```